# Getting exception saying Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Hi am using the simple forward method for which I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed.
```

I know that this exception occurs if I try to do forward after sendRedirect() but in my case it is simple forward still I am getting this exception.
Interesting part is this code works when 2nd if is true. That is,

```
if(strCoyoteRequest.contains("BuildNPlay"))
```

This works fine.

But it does not work on other conditions.

Following is my code

```
    String strForwardPage = new String();
    String strQueryString = request.getQueryString();

    String strCoyoteRequest = request.getRequestURI();

    if(strCoyoteRequest.contains("AdminConsole"))
        strForwardPage = "/AdminConsole/index.jsp";
    else if(strCoyoteRequest.contains("BuildNPlay"))
        strForwardPage = "/BuildNPlay/index.jsp";
    else if(strCoyoteRequest.contains("Portal"))
        strForwardPage = "/Portal/index.jsp";
    else if(strCoyoteRequest.contains("ServiceDashBoard"))
        strForwardPage = "/ServiceDashBoard/index.jsp";

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(strForwardPage);
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: pls give the full stack trace

Comment: Are you using out.print anywhere just check it that could be one reason

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `response.setHeader(...);` before forwarding.  That's committing the response.

The page being forwarded to is the one to do the cache-control in.